# Can I run a pulse tube cooler in reverse to generate pressure oscillations?

Tags: thermodynamics

Since a [pulse tube cooler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_tube_refrigerator) is basically a Stirling engine without moving parts running "in reverse", does that imply that when I keep the cold end at ambient temperature and apply heat to the hot end, I get pressure oscillations? Or do I need the pistons and crankshaft of a standard Stirling engine for that?

I think the question can be boiled down to how the working fluid gets back to the hot end after cooling, and the reason I don't seem to understand this might be that I have not yet fully understood how the buffer volume and orifice work in the pulse tube cooler.